# What is best way to upload video on youtube to a particular account from android app?

Tags: java, video, file-upload, youtube-data-api

i have to upload video to aa particular account on youtube from my android application using java

Comment: u got any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the Youtube API (its actually meant to be used for that).

Here is a [code Sample](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java) i found on Github:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoStatus;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Upload a video to the authenticated user's channel. Use OAuth 2.0 to
 * authorize the request. Note that you must add your video files to the
 * project folder to upload them with this application.
 *
 * @author Jeremy Walker
 */
public class UploadVideo {

    /**
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    private static YouTube youtube;

    /**
     * Define a global variable that specifies the MIME type of the video
     * being uploaded.
     */
    private static final String VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT = "video/*";

    private static final String SAMPLE_VIDEO_FILENAME = "sample-video.mp4";

    /**
     * Upload the user-selected video to the user's YouTube channel. The code
     * looks for the video in the application's project folder and uses OAuth
     * 2.0 to authorize the API request.
     *
     * @param args command line args (not used).
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files
        // to the authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow
        // other types of access.
        List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");

        try {
            // Authorize the request.
            Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadvideo");

            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                    "youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample").build();

            System.out.println("Uploading: " + SAMPLE_VIDEO_FILENAME);

            // Add extra information to the video before uploading.
            Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();

            // Set the video to be publicly visible. This is the default
            // setting. Other supporting settings are "unlisted" and "private."
            VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
            status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

            // Most of the video's metadata is set on the VideoSnippet object.
            VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();

            // This code uses a Calendar instance to create a unique name and
            // description for test purposes so that you can easily upload
            // multiple files. You should remove this code from your project
            // and use your own standard names instead.
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            snippet.setTitle("Test Upload via Java on " + cal.getTime());
            snippet.setDescription(
                    "Video uploaded via YouTube Data API V3 using the Java library " + "on " + cal.getTime());

            // Set the keyword tags that you want to associate with the video.
            List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
            tags.add("test");
            tags.add("example");
            tags.add("java");
            tags.add("YouTube Data API V3");
            tags.add("erase me");
            snippet.setTags(tags);

            // Add the completed snippet object to the video resource.
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

            InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT,
                    UploadVideo.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample-video.mp4"));

            // Insert the video. The command sends three arguments. The first
            // specifies which information the API request is setting and which
            // information the API response should return. The second argument
            // is the video resource that contains metadata about the new video.
            // The third argument is the actual video content.
            YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos()
                    .insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);

            // Set the upload type and add an event listener.
            MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

            // Indicate whether direct media upload is enabled. A value of
            // "True" indicates that direct media upload is enabled and that
            // the entire media content will be uploaded in a single request.
            // A value of "False," which is the default, indicates that the
            // request will use the resumable media upload protocol, which
            // supports the ability to resume an upload operation after a
            // network interruption or other transmission failure, saving
            // time and bandwidth in the event of network failures.
            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

            MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
                public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                    switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                        case INITIATION_STARTED:
                            System.out.println("Initiation Started");
                            break;
                        case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                            System.out.println("Initiation Completed");
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                            System.out.println("Upload in progress");
                            System.out.println("Upload percentage: " + uploader.getProgress());
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                            System.out.println("Upload Completed!");
                            break;
                        case NOT_STARTED:
                            System.out.println("Upload Not Started!");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

            // Call the API and upload the video.
            Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

            // Print data about the newly inserted video from the API response.
            System.out.println("\n================== Returned Video ==================\n");
            System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedVideo.getId());
            System.out.println("  - Title: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println("  - Tags: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTags());
            System.out.println("  - Privacy Status: " + returnedVideo.getStatus().getPrivacyStatus());
            System.out.println("  - Video Count: " + returnedVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount());

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically all you have to do is import the matching library (via gradle) and adapt the upload code from above.